# Selenium standalone server 2.45 ; firefox version 36

Tags: selenium-webdriver

org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Incompatible combination !!
Selenium 2.45 supports only upto FF35

Comment: but 2.44 also not supporting .can u pls help me

Comment: Why would it support when a higher version of Selenium also doesn't support FF41. Instead why don't you try to rollback Firefox to 35 and then try with Selenium 2.45

Comment: Even FF36 is not yet supported !! As I mentioned earlier, FF 35 is supported by Selenium 2.45

Comment: Ideally it should not, did you install FF35 at a different location ? Did you completely uninstall FF36 ? Also after installing FF35 check that auto-updates is turned-off.

Comment: i roll back to FF35.Thq u very much .Now iam able to run my scripts

Comment: Convenient link to d/l FF35: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/35.0b8/

Answer (score 0):

Lucky, in answer to your question, you can find what versions of FireFox a particular Selenium implementation supports by finding the release notes here: https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/py/CHANGES.  For instance, look for "Support for Firefox..."

Comment: Once upon a time the told us. But now not anymore: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/CHANGES (link update)

Comment: thanks @velop, but it seems outdates, as FF 35 is also supported, and the last one mentioned is 29