# "Firefox quit unexpectedly." when running basic Selenium script in Python

Tags: python, html, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape and print the HTML of a page using `Selenium` in `Python`, but every time I run it I get the error message

```
Firefox quit unexpectedly.
```

I'm new to Selenium, so any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm hoping for the simplest fix possible. Thank you!

My code:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://seleniumhq.org/')
print browser.page_source
```

Comment: Using Selenium 2.53.0 and Firefox 47.0 the same problem happens, Firefox 46.0.1 runs okay.

Comment: Having the same problem, how did you fix it?

Answer (score 7):

My experience since the upgrade to Firefox 38.x on Windows a couple of weeks back has been that it has a problem with Selenium 2.45.x. When invoking the browser it produces a "Firefox has stopped working" error which I have to close manually, at which point the test runs. [Others have reported similar issues](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/437).

The solution that worked for me (apart from manually closing the error each time, which got old after a few days) was to uninstall the latest version of Firefox and [downgrade to version 37.0.2](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/) on the machine where I run the tests. Not ideal for security reasons, but OK if you're careful.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading Selenium from 2.45 to 2.47 worked for me.

Selenium 2.46 fixes support for Firefox 38 (and looks like 39 as well).
See the [release notes](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/py/CHANGES)

Answer (score 1):

What version of firefox are you using? firefox 36 started breaking for me with selenium version 2.43.0 . You can upgrade to 2.45 and check. https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8399 They mention at the end that there are fixes for ff 36 in 2.45. For ff 37 and beyond I'm not sure. I downgraded my ff to work with the version of selenium I had.

Comment: Firefox version is the latest, 38.0.1 (I just downloaded it today).

Selenium version is also the latest, 2.45 (also downloaded today).

Any ideas for what I should do?

Comment: Your can refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071406/selenium-standalone-server-2-45-firefox-version-36)

Comment: Latest FF 45 and selenium 2.53 didn't work for me as well